# Error with creating function in R

Tags: r, function, aggregate

I'm trying to create a function as I need to apply the same code multiple times to different columns in my data.

My data (df) looks like this:

```
  WEEK1.x WEEK1.y WEEK2.x WEEK2.y WEEK3.x WEEK3.y
1  660.14       1  690.74       2  821.34       1
2 -482.89      99 -368.12      99 -368.12      99
3  284.48       3  399.90       1  375.32       1
4 -554.18      99 -300.28      99 -300.28      99
```

Then my function looks like:

```
  extra<-function(first_var, second_var){
  df$first_var=ifelse((df$first_var == 99),"99",
                      ifelse((df$first_var %in% c(1,2,3,4,5)),"1-5",NA))
  output=as.data.frame(aggregate(second_var~first_var, data = df, mean))
  return(output)
 }
  WEEK1<-extra("WEEK1.y", "WEEK1.x")
  WEEK2<-extra("WEEK2.y", "WEEK2.y")
```

This then gives me the error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, first_var, value = logical(0)) :
>   replacement has 0 rows, data has 1416

When I press view traceback this is what it says:

> 4. stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
>      "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), domain = NA)
> 5. `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, first_var, value = logical(0))
> 6. `$<-`(`*tmp*`, first_var, value = logical(0))
> 7. extra("WEEK1.y", "WEEK1.x")

I'm not sure what the problem is?

Comment: you didn't pass df to the function as argument  and yet used `df$first_var` inside the function. Try `extra<-function(df, first_var, second_var)`

Comment: The dataframe with the data is called df so this shouldn't be an issue should it? @A.Suliman

Comment: @A.Suliman I did try your suggestion but I get the same error

Comment: I then get an output of two columns. First column is first_var with the value WEEK1.y while the second column is second_var with NA as the value. @A.Suliman

Comment: @A.Suliman No, in this case you are wrong. R will coerce to `factor` when needed. (The suggestion to use `df[,first_var]` is absolutely right, though. +1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working version of your function.
I have used a variant of the suggestion by @A.Suliman, but with `[[`.

```
extra <- function(first_var, second_var){
  df[[first_var]] <- ifelse((df[[first_var]] == 99), "99",
                      ifelse((df[[first_var]] %in% c(1,2,3,4,5)), "1-5", NA))
  fmla <- as.formula(paste(second_var, first_var, sep = "~"))
  aggregate(fmla, data = df, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
}

WEEK1 <- extra("WEEK1.y", "WEEK1.x")
WEEK1
#  WEEK1.y  WEEK1.x
#1     1-5  472.310
#2      99 -518.535


WEEK2 <- extra("WEEK2.y", "WEEK2.x")
WEEK2
#  WEEK2.y WEEK2.x
#1     1-5  545.32
#2      99 -334.20
```

Note that I would also suggest that you pass `df` as an argument to the function. It is generally considered bad practice to rely on objects existing elsewhere than in the function´s environment. In this case, `df` exists in `.GlobalEnv` and you are forcing R to leave th environment where it is needed to find it.

**DATA.**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
  WEEK1.x WEEK1.y WEEK2.x WEEK2.y WEEK3.x WEEK3.y
1  660.14       1  690.74       2  821.34       1
2 -482.89      99 -368.12      99 -368.12      99
3  284.48       3  399.90       1  375.32       1
4 -554.18      99 -300.28      99 -300.28      99
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm new to functions but this makes sense now. I'll use this format going forward.

Comment: @Rui ahaaa NA was produced due to `na.rm=TRUE`. Also nice shoot in `as.fromula`. well done.